# Sharepoint Lists.asmx: The request failed with an empty response

Tags: sharepoint, list

I'm writing a very small app to create and test caml querys for sharepoint. While executing the GetListItems method I'm receiving the following exception;

```
System.Net.WebException: "The request failed with an empty response."
```

The service is located on a https address (ssl). I setup the service as follows;

```
result = new ListService.Lists();
result.Url = siteUrl;
result.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtDomain.Text);
```

I invoke the GetListItems() method as follows;

```
xmlResult = spList.GetListItems(listName, string.Empty, camlQuery, null, string.Empty, null, string.Empty);
```

I'm trying to find out why I'm getting the empty result message. I've also tried other methods (i.e. GetListCollection) but to no avail.

At first I thought that the problem might be the URL (http instead of https), but that is not the case. I even checked it with wireshark to make sure the right URL is used.

Did someone come accross this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I haven't solved this problem before but I would recommend that you do a few things:
1. Test with GetListCollection() since it takes no parameters...sometimes the semantics of parameters in SharePoint are obscure and underdocumented
2. Be sure to use Fiddler2 on your local machine to transparently capture network traffic. It can be configured to inspect HTTPS traffic.
3. Amp up SharePoint logging levels
4. Consult IIS's access and error logs to see if you see anything in there

Comment: @Mark; I've tested the GetListCollection() but that also didn't give me something other than an empty result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OMG...! I've solved it after all. After posting this question, I tried to get hold of the wsdl the check the service itself. When I checked it via internet explorer all was ok. When I tried to add it as a reference in VS it went wrong. So something was not ok. Then it occured to me that there was a new login screen for our company network.

After some quick phonecalls I learned what the problem was; IT Services installed a ISA 2006 server and 'forgot' to tell me. The ISA server was blocking all trafic on the HTTPS port (443) for unkown programs and or clients. That's why internet explorer presented me with a new and shiny login dialog.

Comment: but did you find out how to connect to web services through ISA ?